# Preconditioning : ILU($\emptyset$) factorization and SSOR relation?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let's suppose we have a matrix A = D - L - U , where D,L,U are diagonal , strictly lower and strictly upper triangular,respectively.

Generally the preconditioning matrix, according to SSOR(Symmetric Successive over relaxation)method, of the matrix A  is : $$ M_{SSOR} = \Big(\frac{1}{\omega} D - L\Big)D^{-1}\Big( \frac{1}{\omega}D-U \Big) $$

The preconditioning matrix according to ILU($\emptyset$) is the matrix $M_{ILU(\emptyset)}=\tilde{L}\tilde{U} $ such that $A = \tilde{L}\tilde{U}+R$ where $R$ is the error matrix and is small in some sense.

I have read that for $\omega=1$ the two matrices is almost identical. 
Specifically i have read that :

"the ILU is another algebraic method to obtain a preconditioner matrix $M=(\hat{D} - \hat{L})\hat{D}^{-1}(\hat{D}-\hat{U})$ where again $\hat{D},\hat{L},\hat{U}$ are diagonal,strictly lower and strictly upper triangular , respectively"

Is there any idea what is the relation of $M_{SSOR}$ for $\omega=1$ and $M_{ILU(\emptyset)}$ ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This sounds very strange. Please provide the exact reference.

Comment: i found it in a paper (publication) , can i tell publicly ?

Comment: because its a publication , there is no problem ?

Comment: Just provide the a link to the publisher's copy or the author's private copy and nobody can fault you for anything.

Comment: http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-lat/9608074v1.pdf 
Section 3.2 is the quote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer , so here it is : 
Let's suppose we have a matrix $M = D + L + U $ :

$M_{SSOR} = (D+L)D^{-1}(D+U)$
If we want to write $\tilde{L}\tilde{U}$ obtaining from ILU($\emptyset$) as

$ \tilde{L}\tilde{U} = (\hat{D}+\hat{L})\hat{D}^{-1}(\hat{D}+\hat{U})$ where $\hat{D},\hat{L},\hat{U}$ are diagonal , strictly lower and strictly respectively
then we have : 
$$\hat{D}= diag(\tilde{U})$$
$$\hat{U}=strictly\_upper(\tilde{U})$$
$$\hat{L} = strictly\_lower(\tilde{L})\hat{D}$$
and we can verify  that : 
$$\hat{L} = L$$
So these preconditioners differ at diagonal part $\hat{D}$ and are almost identical